# local variable 'state' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pandas

I don't understand why I have this error in my code.**"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'state' referenced before assignment"** My understanding is that the variable "state" is a local variable, and I didn't use it beyond the function.

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():

    with open("university_towns.txt") as townfile:
        unitowns=townfile.readlines()
    town_list=[]
    for line in unitowns:
        line.rstrip()
        if line[-6:]=="[edit]":
            state = line[:-6]

        elif ' (' in line:
            town = line[:line.index("(")-1]
            town_list.append([state,town])
        else:
            town = line
            town_list.append([state,town])
    unitown_pd=pd.DataFrame(town_list, columns=["State","RegionName"])
    return unitown_pd

get_list_of_university_towns()
```

Comment: What happens if `line[-6:]=="[edit]"` is not true? Where does `state` get assigned?

Comment: add: `state = ''` before this line: `if line[-6:] == '[edit]':`

Comment: @ManishSaraswat I'm not sure that's what he wants to do. Do you really think he wants `['', 'Cambridge']` in his `town_list`? The thing is, I don't know what he _does_ want, which makes it hard to suggest how to get it…

Comment: If you want a good answer to this question, you will need to give us a [mcve], which includes sample input (a stripped-down version of that `univesity_towns.txt` file that still causes the same problem) and expected output.

Comment: Using `endswith` would be preferable to slicing here

Comment: @chepner Normally, definitely—but look at what happens inside the `if` body. This way, there's no chance of an off-by-one error in slicing `state` out of `line` if, e.g., he changes the string later, or mishandles newlines, etc., because he'll never get inside the `if`. So, I think it's reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I need to add a "continue" inside the if.

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():  
    import pandas as pd
    with open("university_towns.txt") as townfile:
        unitowns=townfile.readlines()
    #print(unitowns)
    town_list=[]
    for line in unitowns:
        line=line.rstrip()
        if line[-6:]=="[edit]":
            state = line[:-6]
            #print(state)
            continue

        elif ' (' in line:

            town = line[:line.index("(")-1]
            town_list.append([state,town])
        else:

            town = line
            town_list.append([state,town])
    unitown_pd=pd.DataFrame(town_list, columns=["State","RegionName"])        
    return unitown_pd.head()
```